# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS update broke nvidia dual monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors

I accepted a standard system update request this morning (8/29/18) and when the system restarted, I could no longer access both screens.  I had a situation where I had only mouse access on the left screen, but apps launched on only the right screen.  I have been running this basic config for two years, and have installed new images multiple times, and always accepted updates, but this one busted me.  I resorted to unplugging the right-hand monitor and am now running in single screen mode.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me upgrading 16.04.5 from 4.4.0-127 kernel to 4.4.0-128 and up.
GE9400 video card
A clean install of 18.04.1-ubuntu desktop using proprietary drivers during install had the same issue - only one monitor usable(nvidia-settings had no Xwindow menu items to reconfigure)
A clean install of 18.04.1-mate using open source drivers worked, upgrading that install to proprietary nvidia then worked
I'd try changing your install to open source nvidia and if that works re-install the proprietary drivers
hth

Comment: Thanks, I have been fiddling around and I think I did exactly what you describe, so I now have the dual monitor setup working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have intel graphics and nvidia graphics and solved this problem with this command

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```